# Multi-column stackpanel or alternative

Tags: c#, xaml, stackpanel, windows-store

I have the following XAML code:

```
 <StackPanel Background="White" Margin="267,207,0,44" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
   <ScrollViewer Margin="30,30,0,30" Height="444">
      <ItemsControl Name="ListCountries">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="100">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Red" />
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
                              <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="Black" />
                              <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding desc}" Foreground="Gray" />
                           </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl>
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

I set the itemSource of the itemsControl named ListCountries, with a IEnumerable> and it prints a list of titles, followed by a list of objects of the OtherClass.

My problem is that , the columns that are filled sometimes are bigger than the height of the  Stackpanel that they are inserted to, i want to be able to split my inner list of into columns.

[image]
as you can see in the image, Belgium country gets splited into 2 columns
right now all my countries are single column with vertical scroll.

Comment: Having trouble visualizing what you want, can you provide a visual? Then it should a piece of cake.

Comment: i edited my post , hopefully it will get a bit clearer

Comment: So you would want (for example) Belgium's list to have all its information in the same column so that there's a total of 2 columns for everything instead of 4?

Comment: all the information in the same column is what i have now, one column per country :) , i want to split it if it reaches the bottom. What i have now scrolls down if it passes the stackpanel limit

Comment: this can help you with multi columns [link](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Giving-alternate-color-to-each-row-of-ListBox-in-Windows-phone-7-2280.php)

Comment: Disable the VerticalScrollBarVisibility for your scrollviewer to keep it from allowing vertical scroll, and add a WrapPanel for your ItemsPanel of your embedded ItemsControl. Sorry but I don't have time to make an example at the moment or I'd submit it as an answer.

Comment: hmm i disabled the VerticalBar. and altered my embbbed ItemsControl like so : <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}">, where ItemsPanelTemplate1 is:

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

is that what you meant?

Comment: if you could do an example when you have time , would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `GridView` for this. Here's some code slightly modified from a `Grid` app in Visual Studio

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        Height="600">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>                       
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

Here's a screenshot of what this looks like, with sample data

[image]